# Trying to share a Moose object between some threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, moose

In my moosified TheObject package, I try to do this:

```
around 'new' => sub {
    my $orig=shift;
    my $class=shift;
    my $self=$class->$orig(@_);
    my $shared_self : shared = shared_clone($self);
    return $shared_self;
};
```

Then, in the code with threads:

```
my $obj :shared =new TheObject();
```

But then I get 'Unsupported ref type: CODE' at this line:

```
my $shared_self : shared = shared_clone($self);
```

I am running 5.8.8.

```
perl -Mthreads -le'print $threads::VERSION'
1.74
```

Anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out. My object does in fact contain coderefs within and now that I think about it - how would I even deep copy a coderef in perl?

Answer (score 0):

Moose uses perl-oo technique called inside-out-object

If threads-1.74 shared_clone doesn't support cloning these, try using threads-1.83/threads-shared-1.37, as well as the latest Moose

Comment: I tried upgrading to threads-1.83/threads-shared-1.37 and also Moose. Same thing. This is pretty disappointing. Find it hard to believe I can't use Moose with threads.